# Div problem Is the unit of measure I use is correct?

Tags: html, css

I am preparing a web page, I am not very knowledgeable about this, but what I want to do is one page design but my problem is that the first page is as I want but when I add a second div, the page expands and scrollbars come out. I don't want this.
there is a problem that the page design is different on each device but this is the problem

```
    <div class="kapsayici">
        <div class="üst">
            <h4>PYTHON</h4>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Python Nedir ?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nerelerde Kullanılır ?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kurulum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kayıt Ol</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Giriş Yap</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <video autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="media/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="main_text">
            <h1>ASLA HAYALİNDEN VAZGEÇME</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="kapsayici-2">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>

     CSS 

         *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.kapsayici {
  margin :0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.üst {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}


.menu{
  float: right;
}


.menu li a{
  color :white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 3.8vh;
  left: -3vw;
  letter-spacing: 0.1vw;
  padding:1vw;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 3vw;
  transition: 2s;
}


.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position:relative;
}
.main video{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.main_text{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}

.main_text h1{
  color : white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 30vw;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#kapsayici-2{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 90vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no problem with the unit of measurement. Still, it is preferable to use px as in pixel or percentage.

---

It can be a real mess when you want to create a web page with custom CSS. Please use frameworks such as [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) which will have a common measurement unit and grids will lead to better layout for your webpage.